# Is there a way to expose a value to a pug template other than passing the value in as an argument?

Tags: pug

I have a project that has about 25 pug templates and there are some values I always need to pass into each template (eg. username). Is there a more efficient way (ie. specifying it in one place instead of 25) to give pug access to username? This would also be helpful for config constants that my pug files might need.

Answer (score 0):

I assume ExpressJS framework and you pass response-scoped variables through assigning keys to [`res.locals`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) in a middleware. For application-wide variables use [`app.locals`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals) instead.

Comment: I'm using `res.render()`, which sounds different than what you've described.

Comment: `res.render()` automatically exposes values from `res.locals` to the underlying template. You just have to write and assign a middleware before assigning the routes.